# special character in php array and then insert into excel using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I need to put in the small "TM" in php array and then insert into excel file using phpexcel. However, the excel generated shows the cell as "FALSE" and not "ABC™ 1". May I know how can I put in the small "TM" in php array and pass it into excel file using phpexcel? Below are the current code.

```
$matchPattern = array
    array("ABC™ 1","ABC","ABC"),
    array("XYZ","XYZ","XYZ")
);
```

and then insert into excel with phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($matchPattern, null, 'A1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an encoding issue.

It is highly recommended that you make 100% sure you're [using UTF-8 with PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8), for all steps of the production. This will save you a lot of headaches in the long run.

However, some applications doesn't play too nicely with UTF-8, and expects a different charset out of the box. For these cases you can use `mb_convert_encoding()` to change from UTF-8 to the charset said application accepts.
In MS-Office the "safe" charset depends upon the local Office installation, but going for "iso-8859-1" is generally the safest bet. Just make sure you mark select the charset used in the Excel-document as well, if possible.

Comment: The "safe charset" here is UTF-8.... PHPExcel expects all cell input string values as UTF-8

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for clarifying that. :)